# Hitting deadlock updating WPF UI from 2 callback functions

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, locking, deadlock

I have a WPF app. 
I have a simple UI with a few textboxes. 
Each textbox is updated using a function - Updatefirst(string msg) and updateSecond(string msg)

I have 2 threads that callback to my UI.
Each callback comes with data
once I finish processing the data - I want to update both text box and I do it like this:

```
 lock (updatescreenlock)
{
 Dispatcher.Invoke(new UpdatefirstCallBack(this.Updatefirst), Log.ToString());
}
```

and

```
lock (updatescreenlock)
{
   Dispatcher.Invoke(new updateSecondCallback(this.updateSecond), str);
}
```

I have no control on the rate of those callback to come. 
so I can get as much as 5-10 callbacks in one seconds.
most of the time everything works, but sometimes I get a deadlock. 
one process is stuck inside the Dispacher.Invoke and the others stuck in the lock line.

What am I doing wrong here ?

*** UPDATE 1:

The Update functions just contains txtbox.text updates:
like this - txtCommand.Text = message;
they does not call any other method that does anything else but for txtBox.text = "staff".

** UPDATE 2:
Using BeginInvoke instead of Invoke make the deadlock appear much further away, but eventually I've hit it again.

** Update 3: the update function code:

```
private void UpdateFirst(string message)
        {
            txtTimer.Text = myTime.ToString();
            txt1.Text = val1.ToString();
            txt2.Text = val2.ToString();
            txt3.Text = val3.ToString();
            txt4.Text = val4.ToString();
            txt5.Text = val5.ToString();
            txt1.Text = val6.ToString();
            //if (message.Length > 0) 
            AddLogText(message);
        }

private void AddLogText(string message)
{
    string tmp = txtResults.Text;
    txtResults.Text = DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString() + "\n" + message + "\n" + tmp;
}
```

Comment: Can you show the code of your Updatefirst and updateSecond methods? My first guess is that you're in a loop where the user types in textbox1 and triggers the Changed event, then you set the text of textbox2 and trigger its event recursively.

Comment: updated the question the update function just update textbox.

Comment: Where does this code get called? Do you have a TextChanged event handler?

Comment: no, I have 2 timers (200 ms each) that produces callbacks to the main thread. than in the callback function I do some logic and call the update to add some staff on the screen. so I get many events - they can come at the same time or not, the lock should have make sure than no one tries to update the UI while the other one does it...

Comment: maybe I need to remove the locks and leave it with Dispatcher.BeginInvoke ?

Answer (score 1):

Ultimately this means that one of your Invokes executes code that calls the callback that executes one of the two locks (thus creating a deadlock). Once your in your first lock just step into and through until you land on the second lock.

Comment: this is not the case. all they does it update textbox on the ui (txtItem.text = "staff".

Comment: Well locks do not block access to an object, all they do is prevent another lock from proceeding. So either
a) your doing something else in another thread which stops the first thread with the first lock from completing execution, -or-
b) you have some sort of recursion which is calling a lock from within the code that calls the lock. Those are the only two logical possibilities

Comment: The function that runs inside the lock just update the UI and returns. it doesn't call any other code.

Comment: Well you need to supply more code because what you are describing isn't possible. What calls this function? Not an event that has to do with the value changing and your in an infinite loop i hope?

Comment: no. just txtObject.text = "message" (I have about 7 txtConrols.Text = "" ), but I've notice that some if the object that  Iuse to create the texts are the main thread objects (did not arrived as the parameter) can this be blocking - if someone tries to update an integer in another thread and I'm doing: txtControl.Text = myint.ToString() inside the update function ?

Comment: Well your not answering my question or supplying additional code and what your saying isn't possible so I can't help you

Comment: I'll update the question with the content of the update functions